# How to apply power fit trendline in R or gnuplot?

Tags: r, curve-fitting, gnuplot

For a simple x-y scatter plot, in what way I can apply power fit curve using R or gnuplot? I have a file with two columns.

Comment: I think this would fit better at stackoverflow.

Comment: See section 7 here: http://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/gnuplot.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To give an example for curve fitting with gnuplot, consider the following data set `data.txt`:

```
0.5 0.8
2.4 9.3
3.2 37.9
4.9 68.2
6.5 155
7.8 198
```

The fit with a power law function may look like this:

```
set termoption enhanced
f(x) = a*x**b;
fit f(x) 'data.txt' via a,b

plot 'data.txt' with points title 'data points', \
     f(x) with lines title sprintf('power fit curve f(x) = %.2f·x^{%.2f}', a, b)
```

With the terminal settings

```
set terminal pngcairo size 800,600 font ',12'
```

this gives the result

[image]

This is, of course, the most basic way to fit, the 'specialties' depend on your actual needs.

Comment: Thanks. What if it is not working with redundant data. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712839/power-curve-fitting-in-gnuplot-for-redundant-values])

Comment: @Nari2 I just answered there :-)