# Power curve fitting in gnuplot for redundant values

Tags: gnuplot, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit the power curve into my data with following ***gnuplot code.***

```
set termoption enhanced
f(x) = a*x**b;
fit f(x) 'data.txt' via a,b
plot 'data.txt' with points title 'data points', \
f(x) with lines title sprintf('power fit curve f(x) = %.2f·x^{%.2f}', a, b)
```

It works fine for *non-redundant* data for x axis. (no repeats).

But for following type of data: It is fitting the curve only to points of first x value i.e. 1, (***Starred***).  and not to the whole dataset.

**Data:**

```
1   2194*
1   2675*  
1   1911*  
2   966  
2   1122  
2   951  
2   1356  
3   935  
3   934  
4   851  
4   886  
4   849  
4   597
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set appropriate starting values for `a` and `b`, because nonlinear fitting usually does not have one unique minimum. If you don't specify any starting values, `1` is assumed, which goes in the completely wrong direction in your case.

So, with the following script

```
set termoption enhanced
f(x) = a*x**b
b = -1
a = 2000
fit f(x) 'data.txt' via a,b
plot 'data.txt' with points title 'data points', \
     f(x) with lines title sprintf('power fit curve f(x) = %.2f·x^{%.2f}', a, b)
```

you get a proper fit:

[image]

Comment: Thanks again. I want r^2 value to be displayed. how to do that.

Comment: @Nari2 I have no expertise in the statistics behind the fitting, but gnuplot provides e.g. the variable `FIT_STDFIT` after fitting (set the gnuplot docs about the `fit` command). You can just use `print FIT_STDFIT` to print its value to the standard output, or maybe `set label at graph 0.1, graph 0.1 left sprintf('FIT_STDFIT = %f', FIT_STDFIT)` before the `plot` command.

Comment: I was glad that you answered. I want to know how the values of a, b should be set in case my data keeps changing everyday.